# After text.Split() by line, don't work TryParseHtmlString

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have text file with bunch of hex color codes, but I'm having a hard time understanding why it doesn't convert to Color. If I use a pure string in TryParse, for example:

`ColorUtility.TryParseHtmlString("#040720", out newCol)`
it's working.

My C# code:

```
using UnityEngine;


public class SplitString : MonoBehaviour
{

    public TextAsset TextFile; // txt file 680 lines. content example:   #000000
                                                                       //#040720
                                                                       //#0C090A
    void Start()
    {
        string[] linesInFile = TextFile.text.Split('\n');

        Color newCol;
        int randNum = Random.Range(0, linesInFile.Length);
        if (ColorUtility.TryParseHtmlString(linesInFile[randNum], out newCol))
            transform.GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>().color = newCol;
        else
            print("Parse failed");
    }
}
```

I put this script on Sprite Square and assign text file to it.
TryParse always returns false.

[txt file](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Uhd05hTuHzNVQMf5EoU3LK-UB5rYYbNl/view?usp=sharing)

---

**Edit:**
The comments helped me realize that the problem was the extra line at the end of each string, not a whitespace as thought earlier.

To get rid of the line I did this:

```
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

string pureHex = Regex.Replace(linesInFile[randNum], @"[
]{1,}", "");
```

Now it works perfectly.

Comment: Well you didnt give the world access to your text file - so you could have done the [mcve] thing and demonstrated a few lines to represent the content.  Also, have you debugged this - what did you see?

Comment: Sorry, I have opened access to the file, no I didn't do any of that, I will try.

Comment: you should always try first..

Comment: Strange. I would expect only the **last** color would successfully parse to a Color.  And that's because your text file has `\r\n` and after being split on `\n` would have entries like `#040720\r` and is failing to parse because of the `\r` at the end.  (TryParseHtmlString does not tolerate extra whitespace).  The last entry of the file could potentially have no line ending and therefore parse correctly.  Try parsing `linesInFile[randNum].Trim()`

Comment: Yeah I tried this and also this 'linesInFile[randNum].Replace(" ", ""); linesInFile[randNum].Replace("\n", ""); string pureHex = Regex.Replace(linesInFile[randNum], @"[^\u0009\u000A\u000D\u0020-\u007E]", "*");' It didn't work for me.

Comment: If copy paste a Print of `linesInFile[randNum]` this adds an extra line, I can't get rid of it.

Comment: Can you try `string mockContent = "#000000\r\n#040720\r\n#0C090A\r\n#34282C";        string[] linesInFile = mockContent.Split('\n');` (and use `.Trim()` as per my previous comment) as a test to eliminate the file itself being a problem?  If `TryParse(xxx)` returned false, what was the value of `xxx` at the time?  You should log the string at least: `print("Parse failed: " + linesInFile[randNum])` and be aware of potential hidden characters in your string (probably best to use a debugger to see the string, or log its Length to corroborate that there are no hidden chars.)

Comment: Because you edited the question, it is no longer a question..... 

Answer (score 1):

You have extra whitespace in your string, but `TryParseHtmlString` does not tolerate the extra whitespace.

You split your text file into lines with `\n` but your text file contains `\r\n` line endings.  After splitting, the individual line strings will still contain the extra `\r` character.  For example `#000000\r\n#040720` splits to `[ "#000000\r", "#040720" ]`.  Note the trailing `\r` on the first string.  `TryParseHtmlString` does not tolerate the extra `\r` character.

One easy solution is to trim whitespace from the string you want to parse using `.Trim()`.

```
        string htmlString = linesInFile[randNum].Trim();
        if (ColorUtility.TryParseHtmlString(htmlString, out newCol))
```

Answer (score 0):

The comments helped me realize that the problem was the extra line at the end of each string, not a whitespace as thought earlier.

To get rid of the line I did this:

```
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

string pureHex = Regex.Replace(linesInFile[randNum], @"[
]{1,}", "");
```

Now it works perfectly.